# Powerbi Calculate column to return totals for each category only once

Tags: powerbi, dax, calculated-columns, powerbi-desktop

I will do my best to explain this correctly:

I have a list - by store, by fruit type. I need to create a new column where I have one line of total by store and by fruit (yellow column). In Excel, I can do a formula that does that but I cannot figure out the Dax formula. Or is there another way to do it? Maybe a new table and link them?

[image: result in yellow]

Answer (score 1):

I figured it  out:

> 2 = 
>   CALCULATE(
>       SumX(
>        FILTER(
>        SUMMARIZE(....,"Aggregate", SUM(....])),
>       [Aggregate]>=2
>        ),
>       [Aggregate]
>       ),

)

Comment: Would you please bother to explain your code or at least paste it carefully without loss? Maybe you could format it with daxformatter so we can figure it out ourselves?

Answer (score 0):

PowerBI will aggregate these values for you in a visual. For instance, in a table if you drag the Store # attribute, and the Fruit attribute to a viz:

[image: Example]

Comment: Thank you, but i need to be able to get that column and write another formula to create a stacked visual to show me <2 and >2.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant way of dealing with it, I'll try to keep thinking of alternate solutions... but a possibility would be to create a measure for the different permutations

```
m1 = IF(CALCULATE(COUNT(Sheet1[Fruit]), FILTER(Sheet1,[Store #] = "Store 1"),Sheet1[Fruit]="apple")>2,CALCULATE(COUNT(Sheet1[Fruit]), FILTER(Sheet1,[Store #] = "Store 1"),Sheet1[Fruit]="apple"), 
IF(CALCULATE(COUNT(Sheet1[Fruit]), FILTER(Sheet1,[Store #] = "Store 1"),Sheet1[Fruit]="apple")<2,CALCULATE(COUNT(Sheet1[Fruit]), FILTER(Sheet1,[Store #] = "Store 1"),Sheet1[Fruit]="apple"),0))
```

Out of curiosity, how did you deal with it in excel?

Comment: Thank you so much - i thought of this but the actual data i have has 300+ variations. so this would not be ideal. in Excel i use index match and to only repeat it once but have no idea how to convert it to DAX

Comment: this is a sample formula: =IF(COUNTIF(U$2:$U53,$U53)=1,SUMIF($U$2:$U$4986,INDEX($U$1:$Y$4986,MATCH($U53,$U$1:$U$4986,0),1),$Y$2:$Y$4986),"")